# How to change Windows default locale using Python?

Tags: python, windows, locale, python-2.x

I searched and get this https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html, but can't find a way to change default locale.

Some program need to run under a certain locale. I'm using [Locale Emulator](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator) now and wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: I think either your current solution or [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209) is the best you can do. These only affect the target application, not the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try for e.g.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
```

to change to German locale (substitute 'de_DE' for your required locale)?

In terms of setting the *default* locale, that would be done by your OS, not Python.

Comment: thanks but the program should run in a certain locale not python. So i'm considering change the system default locale.